# Looking for a Canadian vegetation layer?

Tags: data-request

I'm using Landfire cover type for my work in the U.S, but I'm looking for data for all of Canada that will show aspen extent. I've looked at the USGS site using Little (1971) but that is way too general. Preferably something derived from satellite imagery like GAP or Landfire, but I'll take what I can get at this point

Answer (score 1):

[GeoBase](http://www.geobase.ca/) has 
GeoBase - Land Cover, circa 2000-Vector (LCC2000-V)

[Natural Resources Canada](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/resources/data/10788) has many map resources.